# How can I push static log4j log files which I copy from other systems manually into my LogStash ELK server?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am manually copying files from 3 server on a daily basis.
Because of security reasons I cannot setup an automatic forwarder. So I have 3 directories srvapp1 srvapp2 and dbserver and I copy manually the files into these folders.
How can I push these files into logstash? Is there a tool for updating files form log4j of the form app.log app.log.1 ...

As I get this work and can prove the power and validity of ElasticSearch//LogStash/Kibana I may be able to convince management to officially use this in production/development boxes.

Thanks!

Comment: Logstash picks up the files automatically using the `file` input plugin. You don't have to do anything. The files you are copying regularly have the same names with the ones already in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is a bit more complicated(ish). A forwarder is ideal, however sometimes not possible. Here is what I did (which works perfectly fine).

You need a secure connection? Use rsync + ssh!

1. Set up your rsync rules, e.g. rsync your log folder every minute with an append flag. You will have to test your rsync strategy, but it shouldn't be too hard.

So in your crontab you can do something like:

```
* * * * * rsync -avzi --stats -e 'ssh ...' --append-verify FROM_FOLDER TO_FOLDER
```

This will append your log files names safely from A to B. So your copying overhead is also minimal.

1. Configure logstash with a file input that loogs at the target folder for your rsync command. Logstash will automatically pick up all files from there and note all changes. Everything works fine.
2. Standardise your log-names. Logstash will reparse your logfile if your application renames it. The way I solved that is to configure my log-appender to simply use unique names. Instead of having my-log-file.log and rename it at midnight to my-log-file.log.XXXX.XX.XX, I simply use the date pattern in every file from the start. That way, Logstash doesn't get confused about reparsing.

The above solution is fully automatic (so no need to manually copy anything anymore). I hope that helps,

Artur